# How to view several Colorbox images simultaneously after click on wide screen?

Tags: 7, javascript

Usually I see only one big overlay image after click thumbnail with [Colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox).

Is there Colorbox settings to view several overlay images simultaneously on wide screen after click?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose `per page gallery` in colorbox formatter settings like in screenshot :

[image]

Comment: I've tried it. But I see only one big overlay image at screen center - click - other image. But I need to view several images SIMULTANEOUSLY on wide screen. 2 or 3 images simultaneously would be great for wide screen.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uY5KH6Ym-tA

Comment: I've added image in question for better explanation.

Comment: It will give you the arrows which you can theme.